Need h‭elp understanding Google Sheets PERCENTIF
I'm just confused here and would like some more insight into what's happening and if it's on my end or not.
I have a Google Sheet with a bunch of quiz data, and I need to calculate the percent error over all respondents. I have the correct answer in column A, the user's input in the respective row in column B, and error in column C as A-B. $\\left\\{ A, B, C \\in \\mathbb{Z} \\right\\}$ <- LaTeX (A, B, and C all contain integers).
Here's my data:



math input
math correctAnswer
math error




93
93
0


84
84
0


110
111
-1


163
163
0


52
52
0


85
85
0


103
103
0


102
112
-10


98
98
0


136
136
0


70
70
0


119
119
0


63
63
0


174
174
0


82
82
0


109
109
0


92
92
0


34
34
0


95
95
0


126
126
0


78
78
0


67
87
-20


164
164
0


116
116
0


100
100
0


19
122
-103


118
118
0


92
91
1


103
103
0


84
84
0


98
98
0


114
114
0


104
114
-10


53
53
0


121
121
0


136
136
0


140
140
0


76
76
0


150
150
0


80
80
0


125
125
0


129
129
0


109
109
0


112
112
0


174
172
2


161
161
0


147
147
0


63
63
0


93
93
0


113
113
0


138
138
0


168
168
0


69
69
0


77
77
0


105
105
0


41
41
0


79
69
10


45
45
0


33
33
0


121
156
-35


116
116
0


169
169
0


111
111
0


137
138
-1


131
131
0


121
121
0


117
117
0


89
89
0


168
168
0


129
129
0


134
134
0


182
182
0


139
139
0


100
100
0


153
153
0


54
54
0


126
126
0


49
49
0


84
84
0


93
93
0


56
56
0


116
116
0


78
78
0


96
96
0


118
118
0


138
138
0


62
62
0


53
53
0


79
79
0


33
33
0


32
32
0


111
111
0


194
194
0


114
124
-10


169
169
0


118
118
0


126
126
0


80
80
0


133
133
0


50
54
-4


156
176
-20


154
164
-10


34
34
0


50
50
0


92
92
0


109
109
0


143
143
0


107
107
0


113
113
0


120
139
-19


84
84
0


92
92
0


41
41
0


77
77
0


59
59
0


108
108
0


115
115
0


122
122
0


128
134
-6


58
58
0


53
53
0


95
95
0


152
152
0


166
166
0


99
99
0


129
129
0


156
156
0


166
166
0


110
110
0


70
70
0


110
149
-39


127
127
0


121
121
0


100
100
0


120
120
0


73
73
0


50
50
0


154
154
0


72
72
0


116
116
0


107
107
0


158
155
3


125
125
0


70
70
0


46
46
0


103
146
-43


153
153
0


46
46
0


118
118
0


112
112
0


108
108
0


118
118
0


76
120
-44


124
124
0


90
90
0


123
123
0


149
149
0


102
102
0


160
160
0


127
127
0


82
82
0


104
104
0


134
134
0



I originally just used COUNTIF(C2:C10000, "=0")/COUNTA(C2:C10000) and made a formula for it, which worked fine, but someone suggested I use PERCENTIF.
They're the same idea, at least documentation-wise, but COUNTIF(C2:C10000, "=0")/COUNTA(C2:C10000) outputs 0.8773006135, which is correct, whereas PERCENTIF(C2:C10000, "=0") outpus 14%, which is neither correct nor the inverse of 0.8773006135.
Is this just really bad floating point precision error? Are these functions actually different?

Blank cells beyond your data range are by default evaluated to zero → so the 14%
either hardcode the range as
=percentif(C2:C164,0)

OR
=percentif(filter(C2:C,C2:C<>""),0)

& you'll see the 87.73%
